# Python, replace all single/double quotes with new pattern

Tags: python, regex

This is a nodejs regexp that replaces both the quotes to a new pattern that is accepted by json parser.

```
var someStr = "this string has one single quote ': this string has a double quote \""
console.log(someStr.replace(/'|"/g, '\\\\\\"'))
```

It outputs,

```
this string has one single quote \\\": this string has a double quote \\\"
```

I am happy with it. But in python, I translated it as,

```
import re
someStr = "this string has one single quote ': this string has a double quote \""
output = re.sub("'|\"",r"\\\"", someStr)
```

But it outputs,

```
this string has one single quote \\": this string has a double quote \\"
```

Why does python raw string's triple backslashes get written as double backslashes?

Comment: I think that the third backslash has been using to escape the double quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because regular expression substitutions also use \ escapes, extending them to have \n where n is a number refer to subgroups. Example:

```
>>> re.sub(r"a", r"\r", "cat")
'c\rt'
>>> r"\r"
'\\r'
>>> re.sub(r"(a)", r"\1\1", "cat")
'caat'
```

Thus, even with raw strings, you need to escape your backslashes themselves when using re.sub.

Answer (score 4):

This is what the variable output really contains:

```
 'this string has one single quote \\\\": this string has a double quote \\\\"'
```

But the \ is an escape string in python, e.g \\ results in \ if you print it.

Comment: no, it is not a printing error... i did `fd.write` to put the contents into a file. It had double and not four slashes, `this string has one single quote \\": this string has a double quote \\"`.

Comment: If you execute these 3 lines in a python console you will see. Just type output and hit enter, then you will see the real content of the variable output. If you type print(output) the slashes get escaped (The same applies to write).